# InitLoader must be called on the main thread doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask, filefilter

When i try to run function background `Async Task` i get following error saying below error.

```
2021-10-07 11:50:10.045 21569-21636/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.example.jlplayerfilepicker, PID: 21569
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:365)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: initLoader must be called on the main thread
    at androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(LoaderManagerImpl.java:412)
    at filepicker.filter.FileFilter.getFiles(FileFilter.java:19)
    at Activity.SplashScreen.loadVideos(SplashScreen.java:142)
    at Activity.SplashScreen.access$200(SplashScreen.java:39)
    at Activity.SplashScreen$LoadVideos.doInBackground(SplashScreen.java:136)
    at Activity.SplashScreen$LoadVideos.doInBackground(SplashScreen.java:121)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

I call the background task
`new LoadVideos().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);`

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class LoadVideos extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        loadVideos();
        return null;
    }
}

private void loadVideos() {
    FileFilter.getFiles(this, directories -> {
        for (Directory<NormalFile> directory : directories) {
            //list.addAll(directory.getFiles());
            for (int i = 0; i < directory.getFiles().size(); i++) {
                File file = new File(directory.getFiles().get(i).getPath());
                Log.d(TAG, "onResult: " + file.getPath());
                FileStore fs = db.getFileByCustomPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
                AllVideoModel avm = new AllVideoModel();
                avm.setFileName(file.getName());
                avm.setVideoPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
                avm.setFolderName(Objects.requireNonNull(file.getParentFile()).getName());
                avm.setVideoSize(file.length());
                avm.setParentPath(file.getParent());
                StaticConstant.allMediaListWithModel.add(avm);
                StaticConstant.FABbeforeSort.add(avm);
                if (fs == null) {
                    //Add to DataBase
                    FileStore fsNew = new FileStore();
                    fsNew.setName(file.getName());
                    fsNew.setFilePath(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    fsNew.setParent(Objects.requireNonNull(file.getParentFile()).getName());
                    fsNew.setUpdatedAt(new Date());
                    fsNew.setParentPath(file.getParent());
                    db.insertOrUpdateFile(fsNew);
                }
            }
        }
    }, new String[]{".mp4",".ts",".mkv",".mov",
            ".3gp",".mv2",".m4v",".webm",".mpeg1",".mpeg2",".mts",".ogm",
            ".bup", ".dv",".flv",".m1v",".m2ts",".mpeg4",".vlc",".3g2",
            ".avi",".mpeg",".mpg",".wmv",".asf"});
}
```

i have done little search and i don't know how i can solve this issue, and thanks in advance.

So how can i function in background `Async task` ?

**How can I run `loadVideos` in background**

Comment: Do you have any Loaders, or just `AsynTask`

Comment: @Zain yes just a `async task` any update ?

Comment: Can you show the code of `FileFilter.getFiles` .. Did you implement it or is it a library?

Comment: You appear to be using [this](https://github.com/fishwjy/MultiType-FilePicker/blob/master/filepicker/src/main/java/com/vincent/filepicker/filter/FileFilter.java). That code is out of date. However, it will handle the background threading for you, as it uses an (out of date) implementation of `Loader`. You do not need an `AsyncTask` for this. Also, please note that `AsyncTask` is deprecated and obsolete.

Comment: @Zain here is the code for `FileFilter.getFiles` located https://github.com/fishwjy/MultiType-FilePicker

Comment: @CommonsWare is there any other library as same, Or can i use this same `filePIcker` library will it work in android 11 so on ?

Comment: "is there any other library as same" -- I have never looked for one. If I want a "file picker" UI, most likely I would use the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, etc.). "Or can i use this same filePIcker library will it work in android 11 so on ?" -- you have less filesystem access on Android 11+; this library will not change that. And I do not know if there are any limitations specific to the library that might come up due to Android 11+.

Comment: @CommonsWare then how can I run in `FileFilter` background?

Comment: Just use it without an `AsyncTask`. It should be forking its own threads.

Comment: As CommonsWare pointed out, you can remove the AsyncTask as FileFilter.getFiles already handles the background threading for you.. But notice that both AsynTask & Loaders (which is used in the library) are deprecated now

Comment: Note that [AndroidX Loaders](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/loader) are **not** deprecated. Only framework loaders are deprecated (which you never should have been using in the first place).